# Somar número em array e listá-lo

Tags: javascript, html, array

Qual a maneira mais simples de se fazer com *array* uma espécie de banco onde eu deposito um valor em um *array* e mostro o mesmo depois. A minha dificuldade está em modificar o *array*, onde o valor inicial seria 0 e daí conforme for depositando o valor vai aumentando baseado na minha lógica ali bem simples.

```js
var dinheiro = [];
 var totalSaque;
 
 function depositar() {
  

 
  var deposito = document.getElementById("txt").value;

     totalSaque = dinheiro + deposito;
      
      document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "--valor depositado--";


  
 }



 function verConta() {
  
  document.getElementById("ex").innerHTML = totalSaque;
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "";
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>banco</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="float: left;">No Caixa:</h1><h1 id="ex" style="float: left;">0</h1>

</br></br></br></br></br>

<input id="txt" type="number">

<button onclick="depositar()">Depositar</button>
<button onclick="verConta()">ver Conta</button>


<p id="dep"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tem que armazenar em um array? Caso não precise, é somente somar o valor depositado com o que está na conta.

Comment: Mas quando eu pressiono o botão  "ver conta" depois de ter depositado por exemplo 20 e 10 por exemplo. aparece o 10 e não 30 entendeu? eu tenho alguma lógica muito errada, mas não sei o que é

Comment: Vou postar o exemplo sem o array, caso você ainda queira com o array então posto com outra resposta.

Comment: Se puder postar as duas versões estarei deveras agradecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem o array ficaria assim:

```js
var totalSaque = 0;
 
 function depositar() {
 
  var deposito = document.getElementById("txt").value;

     totalSaque += parseInt(deposito);
      
      document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "--valor depositado--";
  
 }

 function verConta() {
  
  document.getElementById("ex").innerHTML = totalSaque;
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "";
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>banco</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="float: left;">No Caixa:</h1><h1 id="ex" style="float: left;">0</h1>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<input id="txt" type="number">

<button onclick="depositar()">Depositar</button>
<button onclick="verConta()">ver Conta</button>


<p id="dep"></p>

</body></html>
```

Com o array:

```js
var dinheiro = [];
 
 function depositar() {
 
  var deposito = document.getElementById("txt").value;

     dinheiro.push(parseInt(deposito));
      
      document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "--valor depositado--";
  

  
 }



 function verConta() {
  
   var soma = dinheiro.reduce(function(acumulador, valorAtual) { return acumulador + valorAtual;});
  
  document.getElementById("ex").innerHTML = soma;
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "";
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>banco</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="float: left;">No Caixa:</h1><h1 id="ex" style="float: left;">0</h1>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<input id="txt" type="number">

<button onclick="depositar()">Depositar</button>
<button onclick="verConta()">ver Conta</button>


<p id="dep"></p>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

O problema do código é que ele não está somando onde deve, soma em uma variável que sequer tem um valor. Por alguma razão acredito que está pensando que o *array* é um tipo que vai mantendo a soma, o que está longe de ser verdade. É mais simples que isto:

```js
var total = 0;
function depositar() {
    total += parseInt(document.getElementById("txt").value);
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "--valor depositado--";
}
function verConta() {
    document.getElementById("ex").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>banco</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="float: left;">No Caixa:</h1><h1 id="ex" style="float: left;">0</h1>
        </br></br></br></br></br>
        <input id="txt" type="number">
        <button onclick="depositar()">Depositar</button>
        <button onclick="verConta()">ver Conta</button>
        <p id="dep"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/SumNumber.js).

Se quiser mostrar tudo:

```js
var dinheiro = [];
var total = 0;
function depositar() {
    var valor = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt").value)
    total += valor;
    dinheiro.push(valor); //somente se for fazer algo com este valor depois
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML += valor + "<br>";
}
function verConta() {
    document.getElementById("ex").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>banco</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="float: left;">No Caixa:</h1><h1 id="ex" style="float: left;">0</h1>
        </br></br></br></br></br>
        <input id="txt" type="number">
        <button onclick="depositar()">Depositar</button>
        <button onclick="verConta()">ver Conta</button>
        <p id="dep"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/SumNumber2.js).

Answer (score 2):

Para trabalhar com `arrays` você pode iniciar a variável da seguinte forma: `totalSaque = new Array();` ou `totalSaque = [];`

Para armazenar os valores também é muito simples, você utilizar o método `push` ou informar o índice que você quer alterar, criar, modificar ou remover. Ex:

```
totalSaque.push("Novo-valor");

/* Ou */

totalSaque[1] = "Novo-valor";
```

Lista-lo também não é dor de cabeça, você pode fazer utilizando a estrutura de repetição [**for**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) ou seus semelhantes, como exemplo: [**for..in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) ou [**for..of**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Com exemplo fica mais fácil. Segue abaixo:

```js
  const depositos = new Array();
 
 function depositar() {
    let deposito = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    
    // Adiciona um novo valor no array
    depositos.push(deposito)
    
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = "--valor depositado--";
  }
  
  function verConta() {
    let html = "";
    let total = 0;
    
    // Percorre todos os valores salvos no array
    for (let deposito of depositos) {
    
      // Captura o valor
      html += "Deposito R$" + deposito + "<br>";
      
      // Soma total com ele mesmo + o valor do deposito
      total += parseInt(deposito);
    }
    
    html += "<hr>R$" + total;
  
  document.getElementById("ex").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("dep").innerHTML = html;
 }
```

```html
<h1 style="float: left;">No Caixa:</h1>
<h1 id="ex" style="float: left;">0</h1>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<input id="txt" type="number">

<button onclick="depositar()">Depositar</button>
<button onclick="verConta()">ver Conta</button>


<p id="dep"></p>
```